# How to open Crystal Report from Gridview row command button dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, crystal-reports

I face problem in my code after inclusion of Crystal report code in my asp.net C# program.

I have a Cheque.aspx file in a web application set up in VS2010 that includes a ListBox of all "Payees" being loaded on Page_Load. Click on a payee(OnSelectedIndexChanged()) result in a dynamically-generated GridView with all cheques of that payee in individual separate rows. The Gidview last column includes various command buttons(Edit, Delete, Submit, Print). With "Print" onclick event I want to open a crystal view report for that cheque for onward print activity. (Have installed Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0).
In the aspx file I have added the Register Assembly command as follow:

```
 `<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>`
```

The GridView  and CR Tag is included as below:

```
 <div class="scroll">
 <asp:GridView ID="ChqOuterGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                             OnDataBound="ChqOuterGridView_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowDataBound"
                            DataKeyNames="Id,ChqNo,Action,TotChqAmt,PayeeName" Caption="" 
                             BorderStyle="Solid" OnRowEditing="ChqOuterGridView_RowEditing" 
                            OnRowDeleting="ChqOuterGridView_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="ChqOuterGridView_RowUpdating"
                             OnRowCommand="ChqOuterGridView_RowCommand">
 <columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cheque No" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblCHqNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ChqNo")%>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="90px" HeaderText="Total Cheque Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblTotAmt" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("TotChqAmt")))*1000000).ToString("##,##0.######") %>'>
         </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="BtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" SkinID="1" Text="" />
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" SkinID="2" Text="" />
   <br />
       <asp:Button ID="BtnPrintCheque" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Print Cheque" CommandArgument="Print"/>
   <br />
      <asp:Button ID="BtnSend" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Send  to Accountant" CommandArgument="Send"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
 </div>
 <div>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crptViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"/>
 </div>
```

The Crystal Report code in the code behind (cheque.aspx.cs) on the gridview_RowUpdating button click event is as follow:

```
public void ChqOuterGridView_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  string ChqNo = (string)ChqOuterGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["ChqNo"];
  if (CommandArgument == "Print")
  {
      ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
      rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/CR/PrintCheque.rpt"));

  DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();

  dataTable1.Columns.Add("PayeeName", typeof(String));
  dataTable1.Columns.Add("AmountinFigures", typeof(Decimal));

  DataRow dtRow = dataTable1.NewRow();

  dtRow["PayeeName"] = ChqOuterGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["PayeeName"];
  dtRow["AmountinFigures"] = ChqOuterGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["TotChqAmt"];

  dataTable1.Rows.Add(dtRow);
  MyDataSet mds = new MyDataSet();
  mds.Tables.Add(dataTable1);

  rptDoc.SetDataSource(mds);
  crptViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc; 
//   CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

The dataset is created in ~/App_Code/MyDataSet.xsd and the crystal report is set with its two columns accordingly.  The web.config has the following relevant entries:

```
 <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
          <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
            <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
            <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>

<assemblies>  
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</assemblies>
```

If I remove Crystal report tags and related code, the ListBox *OnSelectedIndexChanged()* works fine and Gridview is displayed., however after inclusion of Crystal Report tags, the page is loaded and Listbox elements are shown but clicking on an element does not have any effect.

Can anyone suggest what may be the reason for ListBox items not triggering the  OnSelectedIndexChanged()?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't triggering, or is it failing in the event handler? Have you stepped through it by setting a breakpoint in the selected index changed handler?

Comment: @Ron  yes I tried that but  breakpoint is not triggered.

Comment: Resolved.The problem was with we.config add key ResourceUri entry: '<businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <rptBuildProvider>
        <add embedRptInResource="true"/>
      </rptBuildProvider>
      <crystalReportViewer>
        <add key="UseBrowserLocale" value="true"/>
        <add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13"/> 
          </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>'